# PHP files open as text in my browser

Tags: php, apache

My php files if opened via the localhost (i used httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi and the apache server is running with PhpMyAdmin files placed in apache/htdoc) are shown as text files in my browser:

for example if i wrote a something in my php file, as soon as i open that file either via my local webserver or opening the file directly, it will be shown as text! Please help.

Comment: does the phpinfo() works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't configured Apache to send PHP files to the parser. As such, the format will remain unrecognized and be displayed as text or be downloaded to the client. Assuming you're using a PC or a Mac, most every guide to setting up Apache with PHP will explain how to do this.